# Gigabyte r5 230 card showing hd 6640

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

Bought an r5 230 for my optiplex 990 sff
Installed the driver from the driver CD
but it is shown as hd 6450 in the catalyst control center 
Could the card be faulty or the drivers or did i get fooled

[image: picture of card box]

[image: shown as on the driver]

I use win 10 pro

Comment: You don't happen to have a picture of the card as well? You can always try downloading a new driver and see if it changes the information.

Comment: Also, check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/857761/are-the-radeon-r5-230-and-hd-6450-the-same-video-card

Comment: Driver update done no change in the scene

Comment: More people with similar problems: http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/377534-radeon-r5-230-turned-hd-6450-a.html
If it works correctly, I wouldn't worry too much about it showing the wrong thing.

Comment: It appears spec wise you have what the R5 Series cards say they are supposed to have from the [vendor site](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r5)... If you can look at the card and maybe get some numbers off of it you can confirm as well. Vendor site for [HD 6450](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/6000/6450) with a pic as well as the vendor site got the [R5 Series](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r5) with a pic.... you tell us.

Comment: Add more detail of else this is too broad... thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the core clock from your picture, It's the right card:
http://www.gigabyte.se/Graphics-Card/GV-R523D3-1GL-rev-10#sp
compared to the 6450
http://www.gigabyte.com/Graphics-Card/GV-R645OC-1GI#sp

But as far as I can see, they are essentially the same card.
Just re-released under another name. So it IS the HD6450 chipset.

Answer (score 0):

AMD have rebadged a a whole swathe of cards over the past couple of years.
Any "Rx xxx" card is really an "HD xxxx" underneath.

My own HD 7950 is also sold as an R9 280. The 7970 is an R9 280X etc etc.
This GPU comparison page shows some of the re-badges, but not all - http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php